# Insert Data to MySQL db from HTML form using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to insert new record to SQL database using PHP from a HTML form.

I made a form using Post method

```
<form name="CreatNewMCQ" action="create.php" method="POST">
```

with a button to submit

```
<button type="submit" form="CreateNewMCQ">CREATE</button>
```

what I want to do is when I press the button, it will call create.php which is

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$user = "admin";
$pass = "admin";
$dbname = "examples";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $user, $pass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$year = $_POST['year'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO cars (id, name, year)
VALUES ($id, $name, $year)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Tạo mới thành công";
} else {
    echo "Lỗi: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

then insert data from form to SQL database (id, name, year from the form).
I got some errors in SQL syntax. What mistake did I make?

Comment: If you got any error message, You can share the error messages with your question.

Comment: **Start by posting the error you get, this will help us to help you.** I will assume your error is at your $sql line, you might want to have some single quotes there... `$sql = "INSERT INTO cars (id, name, year) VALUES ($id, '$name', '$year')";` if you have spaces and other some other characters it will break your query... Further on you should really learn about prepared statements since you are already using mysqli, to avoid MySQL Injections.

Comment: Some error: Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\create.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\create.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: year in C:\xampp\htdocs\create.php on line 16

Comment: @TrầnVũAnhDũng have you included those fields in your form? It looks to me they  are either empty or non-existent from your form submit.

Comment: Yes I have. I used this: <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="Enter brand">

Comment: @TrầnVũAnhDũng for all the 3? id, name, year? Because your error message points to the fact those are empty or non-existent when you submit your form, what you get from `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: of course not. just an example. I used 3 different input tag

Comment: @TrầnVũAnhDũng can you show the form html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure all post values are getting correctly. You should make a condition check before inserting the data, For ex:

```
$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '';
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
$year = isset($_POST['year']) ? $_POST['year'] : '';

if($id && $name && $year){
$sql = "INSERT INTO cars (id, name, year)
VALUES ($id, '$name', '$year')";
}else{
  return "required fields are missing";
}
```

NB: Please post your html if possible.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection.*/

$servername = "localhost";
$user = "admin";
$pass = "admin";
$dbname = "examples";

$link = mysqli_connect($servername, $user, $pass, $dbname);

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Attempt insert query execution
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$year = $_POST['year'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO cars (id, name, year)
VALUES ($id, '$name', '$year')";

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: [`new mysqli` already does the connect within.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

Comment: thank you for replying, but i still got the same errors as I did. "Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\create.php on line 18"

Comment: can you post your form inputs?

Comment: your id may be autoincrement, so it is not needed to get from form and insert

Comment: My form : <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" id="id" placeholder="Input ID">

Comment: what is the type of your id in the database? it may be an integer but you enter the text from from

Comment: I don't set autoincrement for id on my database, and those name and year parameters have the same error.

Comment: what is the type of your id in the database?

Comment: its integer, and I have type number on ID input

Comment: use this in your form `<input type="number" name="id" class="form-control" id="id" placeholder="Input ID">`

Comment: Undefined id or name and year?

Answer (score -2):

```
HTML Form :
<html>
<form name="test" method="post">
Enter name:<input type="text" name="name"/> <br>
Enter year :<input type="text" name="year"/><br>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="save" />
</form>
</html>
php code  :

<?php
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","passward");
$select_db=mysql_select_db("Atul",$conn);
if($conn)
{
    echo "connected";
}
else
{
    echo "Please try again";
}

if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $year=$_POST['year'];
    $insert_record="insert into test (name,year) values("$name","$year");
    $result=mysql_query($insert_record);
    if($result)
    {
        echo "Record inserted successfully";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "please try again";
    }
}
?>
```